# AWS S3 - Virtual Network Drive Implementation

Tags: windows, filesystems, device-driver, wdk, windows-kernel

### Environment

- Windows OS x64
- AWS S3 Storage
- C++

### Use-case

Virtual Folder/'Network Drive' mapped to AWS S3 storage.
Data read/written to/from the local folder/drive should be relayed to S3.
Read-a-head and caching are to be implemented/incorporated.
The nature of the data stored is Video files.
The folder is to be accessed by system services.

### Questions at hand

1. How should I approach this w/ implementation?
2. Does this mandate implementing a File Sys Filter Driver?
3. Is there any other approach
   to be considered?

Comment: I believe this is already implemented by various 3rd-party products. I googled "map a drive to S3" and found some.  I believe it would be implemented as a file system driver (perhaps a network redirector, or a mini redirector), but not a file system _filter_ driver.  Also, [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/getting-started-use-fileshare.html) suggests you can use a native NFS client to access S3.

Comment: Yup, using the file gateway will do for individual files though the files that I am using are 100ds of MB and have a subset constantly changed/updated, I need a solution that will also enable local caching for a subset of the file...I am currently considering a VFS Samba plugin...

Comment: Windows implements caching for file systems.  It might be worth researching whether that is suitable, or whether it can be tuned to your satisfaction, before developing a driver.  (Are samba VFS modules applicable to Windows clients?)

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742613.aspx) among others.
"Frequently referenced files tend to remain in cache memory automatically"
"The ... file cache does attempt to improve upon the apparent responsiveness of this serial, sequential disk file activity by prefetching blocks "

Comment: Samba VFS modules is certainly something I am investigating, VFS plugin versioning seems tricky ( mandate a compatible SMB version installed ), and, relay on internal libraries ( to the best of my knowldge, VFS modules can't just compile w/ the stock apt-get SMB modules, U should actually have SMB compilation env to be able to build VFS modules )

Answer (score -1):

I know that 'MoSMB server'-an SMB3 server on linux supports S3 object stores on the storage side. It exports S3-buckets(on amazon or minio) as SMB2/3 shares. These shares can be mapped as network drive on any windows clients and they can be used as filesystem.